# Is there a way to get a filtered list of questions I have asked that have answers, none of which I have accepted?

Tags: support

Like the title says, I'd like to get an overview of all the questions which have answers that I have not yet accepted.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure :)

Search for:

> user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1

`answers:1` means questions with *at least* 1 answer, not 1 answer in total.

[Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: Wow, what a great list of search options.  And to think I had been drilling down my list of questions manually...

Comment: Yeah I used to do the same thing until someone on MSO pointed me to that page. Oh the wasted minutes...